# How to import an Anaconda environment .yml in virtualenv?

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, virtualenv, jupyter

I just need to import an Anaconda .yml environmental file in virtualenv virtual environment.

The reason I need to do this is because on nVidia Jetson TX2 developer board I cannot install and run Anaconda distribution (It is not compatible with ARM architecture). Virtualenv and Jupyter, instead, are installed and run flawlessly.

The .yml file is listed like this:

```
name: tfdeeplearning
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bleach=1.5.0=py35_0
  - certifi=2016.2.28=py35_0
  - colorama=0.3.9=py35_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py35_0
  - decorator=4.1.2=py35_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py35_0
  - html5lib=0.9999999=py35_0
  - icu=57.1=vc14_0
  - ipykernel=4.6.1=py35_0
  - ipython=6.1.0=py35_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py35_0
  - ipywidgets=6.0.0=py35_0
  - jedi=0.10.2=py35_2
  - jinja2=2.9.6=py35_0
  - jpeg=9b=vc14_0
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py35_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py35_3
  - jupyter_client=5.1.0=py35_0
  - jupyter_console=5.2.0=py35_0
  - jupyter_core=4.3.0=py35_0
  - libpng=1.6.30=vc14_1
  - markupsafe=1.0=py35_0
  - matplotlib=2.0.2=np113py35_0
  - mistune=0.7.4=py35_0
  - mkl=2017.0.3=0
  - nbconvert=5.2.1=py35_0
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py35_0
  - notebook=5.0.0=py35_0
  - numpy=1.13.1=py35_0
  - openssl=1.0.2l=vc14_0
  - pandas=0.20.3=py35_0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py35_0
  - path.py=10.3.1=py35_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py35_0
  - pip=9.0.1=py35_1
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py35_0
  - pygments=2.2.0=py35_0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py35_0
  - pyqt=5.6.0=py35_2
  - python=3.5.4=0
  - python-dateutil=2.6.1=py35_0
  - pytz=2017.2=py35_0
  - pyzmq=16.0.2=py35_0
  - qt=5.6.2=vc14_6
  - qtconsole=4.3.1=py35_0
  - requests=2.14.2=py35_0
  - scikit-learn=0.19.0=np113py35_0
  - scipy=0.19.1=np113py35_0
  - setuptools=36.4.0=py35_1
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py35_1
  - sip=4.18=py35_0
  - six=1.10.0=py35_1
  - testpath=0.3.1=py35_0
  - tk=8.5.18=vc14_0
  - tornado=4.5.2=py35_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py35_0
  - vs2015_runtime=14.0.25420=0
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py35_0
  - wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.0.2=py35_0
  - win_unicode_console=0.5=py35_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py35_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=vc14_0
- pip:
  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - jupyter-client==5.1.0
  - jupyter-console==5.2.0
  - jupyter-core==4.3.0
  - markdown==2.6.9
  - prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
  - protobuf==3.4.0
  - tensorflow==1.3.0
  - tensorflow-tensorboard==0.1.6
  - werkzeug==0.12.2
  - win-unicode-console==0.5
prefix: C:\Users\Marcial\Anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning
```

Comment: Does your file really look like exactly that? I ask because it is an invalid YAML file, caused by the "key" `- pip` at the root level. Are you sure that and the value should not be indented?

Answer (score 11):

pip can install from a `requirements.txt` file, which would look like
the items in the sequence that is the value for the key
`pip` in your `.yml` file, but without the dashes:

```
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jupyter-client==5.1.0
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0
markdown==2.6.9
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
protobuf==3.4.0
tensorflow==1.3.0
tensorflow-tensorboard==0.1.6
werkzeug==0.12.2
win-unicode-console==0.5
```

Assuming that the end of your file actually looks like:

```
  .
  .
  .
  - wincertstore=0.2=py35_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=vc14_0
  - pip:
    - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
    - jupyter-client==5.1.0
    - jupyter-console==5.2.0
    - jupyter-core==4.3.0
    - markdown==2.6.9
    - prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
    - protobuf==3.4.0
    - tensorflow==1.3.0
    - tensorflow-tensorboard==0.1.6
    - werkzeug==0.12.2
    - win-unicode-console==0.5
prefix: C:\Users\Marcial\Anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning
```

(i.e. the entry for pip is indented to make this a valid YAML file),
and is named `anaconda-project.yml`, you can do:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(open('anaconda-project.yml'))

requirements = []
for dep in data['dependencies']:
    if isinstance(dep, str):
        package, package_version, python_version = dep.split('=')
        if python_version == '0':
            continue
        requirements.append(package + '==' + package_version)
    elif isinstance(dep, dict):
        for preq in dep.get('pip', []):
            requirements.append(preq)

with open('requirements.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for requirement in requirements:
       print(requirement, file=fp)
```

resulting in a `requirement.txt` file, which can be used with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Please note:

- the non-pip packages might not be available from PyPI
- the current pip version is 18.1, the one in that requirements list is old
- that according to the official YAML FAQ, using `.yml` as an
  extension for your YAML file should only be done if the recommended
  `.yaml` extension. On modern filesystems that is never the case. I
  don't know if Anaconda is, as so often, non-conform, or that you
  have a choice in the matter.
- since the introduction of binary wheels a few years ago, and many
  packages supporting them, it is often (and for me always) possible
  to just use virtualenvs and pip. And thereby circumventing the
  problems caused by Anaconda not being 100% compliant and not being
  up-to-date with all its packages (compared to PyPI).

Comment: Nice suggestion, I created a gist for it: https://gist.github.com/tijsmaas/00bf6aa4fa02e4f9a7e41f5ac2c26cff